# Is it possible to implement a rating system with game center?

Tags: ios, game-center

Is is possible to use iOS Game Center to implement a rating system for multiplayer games, where a player's rating go up if they win battles and down if they lost? From my understanding, it's primary use is to store high scores and achievements.

Answer (score 0):

I use a dedicated server for that using ELO rating to rate the players. I don't think you can achieve rating with Game Center.